# Ruby - Nokogiri xml search with 2 conditions

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have an xml file.

```
<generic:Obs>
  <generic:ObsKey>
    <generic:Value id="TIME_PERIOD" value="2020"/>
    <generic:Value id="SPECIFICATION" value="SSL05"/>
    <generic:Value id="MONTH" value="A02"/>
    <generic:Value id="FREQ" value="A"/>
  </generic:ObsKey>
  <generic:ObsValue value="100.56"/>
  <generic:Attributes>
    <generic:Value id="NOTE_SPECIFICATION_2" value="SSL05"/>
    <generic:Value id="DECIMALS" value="2"/>
  </generic:Attributes>
</generic:Obs>
```

I need to show the `<generic:ObsValue value="x"/>` from the group `<generic:Obs>` if the `<generic:Value id="TIME_PERIOD" value="2020"/>` and `<generic:Value id="MONTH" value="A02"/>` match.

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(URI.open("https://xml.de"))
@ObsValue = doc.xpath('//obs//obskey/@id="TIME_PERIOD"').....
```

I really cant find the solution. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

So one issue is you have an undefined namespace `generic:`.
For the sake of this example I will add one to your XML.

```
DOC = %Q(
<generic:Obs xmlns:generic="http://example/root">
  <generic:ObsKey>
    <generic:Value id="TIME_PERIOD" value="2020"/>
    <generic:Value id="SPECIFICATION" value="SSL05"/>
    <generic:Value id="MONTH" value="A02"/>
    <generic:Value id="FREQ" value="A"/>
  </generic:ObsKey>
  <generic:ObsValue value="100.56"/>
  <generic:Attributes>
    <generic:Value id="NOTE_SPECIFICATION_2" value="SSL05"/>
    <generic:Value id="DECIMALS" value="2"/>
  </generic:Attributes>
</generic:Obs>
)
```

Personally unless you have a reason to retain them I would just remove the namespaces for ease of parsing

```
doc = Nokogiri.parse(DOC)
doc.remove_namespaces!
```

Then we can use the following XPath:

```
//Obs
  /ObsKey[
    ./Value[@id="TIME_PERIOD" and @value="2020"] and 
    ./Value[@id="MONTH" and @value="A02"]
  ]
  /following-sibling::ObsValue/@value
```

To break this down:

1. `//Obs` - Start at the Obs node
2. `/ObsKey[./Value[@id="TIME_PERIOD" and @value="2020"] and ./Value[@id="MONTH" and @value="A02"]]` find ObsKey child Node where the relative child Value nodes meet the desired criteria e.g. (Value.id = "TIME_PERIOD" AND Value.value = "2020") AND (Value.id = "MONTH" AND Value.value = "A02")
3. `/following-sibling::ObsValue/@value` relative to that Node (if one exists) select the following sibling ObsValue node and then select its @value attribute

Example: ([Working Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/GlitteringExpensiveFunction#main.rb))

**Success**:

```
doc.at_xpath('//Obs
  /ObsKey[
    ./Value[@id="TIME_PERIOD" and @value="2020"] and 
    ./Value[@id="MONTH" and @value="A02"]
  ]
  /following-sibling::ObsValue/@value')&.value
#=> "100.56"
```

**Failure**:

```
# changed the TIME_PERIOD value 
doc.at_xpath('//Obs
  /ObsKey[
    ./Value[@id="TIME_PERIOD" and @value="2022"] and 
    ./Value[@id="MONTH" and @value="A02"]
  ]
  /following-sibling::ObsValue/@value')&.value
#=> nil
```